# Java Generics always for collections

Tags: java, generics

I have a question about Java Generics. If I define a class like this:

```
public Test<String> ...
```

Does this mean that my class now acts like a collection type for Strings? For example when seeing it like this List I know that it is a List of Strings. Does the <> always mean it's a collection (general meaning, not the actual Collection type)?

thanks,

Comment: You are missing basic language theory. Start to read about [Java collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) and [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I did read the java docs on the oracle site and some oYther sites, I was getting tripped up on the <>  as most sites show generics being used with collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It just means that your type is parameterized with the type String. There are plenty of non-collection generic types. See `Callable<T>`, `Future<T>`, `Comparator<T>` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 0):

You should start from the beginning: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/generics.html

Long story short: generics are a completely different concept from collections. Java collections use generics since they were introduced, but you can still use non-generics versions of them.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not! It only mean that `Test` is parametrized with the String.

Read oracle [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) for good understanding of Generics.

Answer (score 0):

No.

To do what you mean you add `extends Collection<T>` to your class declaration